# Stream audio file dynamically generated directly on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following the Adrian's solution with `SpeechSynthesizer` (and slightly modifying it) in the below thread I have successfully generated an audio response which generates "captcha.wav" as a download. 
[How to implement Custom Audio Capcha in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783127/how-to-implement-custom-audio-capcha-in-asp-net)

However I want the generated audio to be available to be played on the page when the user clicks on a button(This is for audio captcha). How can I do this in ASP.Net with C#?

So far I tried following this and it has not worked out

```
<embed src="captcha.aspx">
<object data="captcha.aspx">
```

Comment: Please check this link- http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/285580-Captcha-with-Audio-Sound-using-asp-net-C.aspx

Comment: unfortunately I can't use recaptcha.