# ASP.Net string to audio

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, captcha

Am doing a readout of Random generated string for captcha purposes(in ASP.Net C#). I have implemented this using Adrian's solution using System.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer in the following link

[How to implement Custom Audio Capcha in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783127/how-to-implement-custom-audio-capcha-in-asp-net)

But my client is not happy with the voice as it is clumsy some times. For example J is read out as G.(I have managed to split the string into character array and substitute J with 'jay' which reads it correctly).
Since it is a server we are going to put this on, the number of voice that is installed is just one, which is Microsoft sams. So am looking for any other option which will read it out better. I cannot use a third party service or API(like recaptcha) as it is a banking website(you know security reasons)

Comment: Sorry I have edited the original question. Hope it makes sense now. Fit of anxiety...

Answer (score -1):

Well, you asked for a better way: just use a well-known good CAPTCHA like [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) which does the heavy lifting for you. Good text-to-voice -synthesizers are not cheap.