# asp.net embed video player doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, embed, video-player

I am trying to display a video on my aspnet project I couldnt succeed. here is my rendered html code.

```
<object width="300" height="200"><embed src="uploaded_files/dde35c21-5261-e211-a320-0025d3b48279_609441313.wmv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></object>
```

I checked the link and link works. But on the webpage, I right-click the where video-player is  supposed to be, I see the flash-player menu. and on that menu, it displays the version of flash player at the bottom and it says "Video is not loaded" at the top of the same menu.

what do you think is the problem?

Comment: I know that the browsers did not direct support the `.wmv` files. You need to convert it to a format that browser can play.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. but what is the best solution to this? I want the user to display upload and watch an kind of video format

Comment: Maybe this answer can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648471/how-to-play-audio-and-video-files-in-web-browser/10648724#10648724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video player code

```
   <object height="320px" width="240px" type ="video/x-ms-wmv">
        <param name="src" value="http://localhost/MyMovie.wmv" />
    </object>
```

[Refer this link to more details](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Media-Player.aspx)